# ASP.NET C# Generate Table Dynamically doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table

I've been trying to generate a table with n number of rows. Being used to PHP makes this all the worst. I tried the following code:

```
using System.Data;

// Create a DataTable instance
DataTable dTbl = new DataTable("myDynamicTable");

// Create a DataColumn instances

DataColumn dValue = new DataColumn();
DataColumn dMember = new DataColumn();

dValue.ColumnName = "Id";
dValue.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");

dMember.ColumnName = "Name";
dMember.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");

// Add these DataColumns into the DataTable

dTbl.Columns.Add(dValue);

dTbl.Columns.Add(dMember);
DataRow myrow = dTbl.NewRow();

myrow["Id"] = 1;
myrow["Name"] = "Tux";

// Add the row into the table

dTbl.Rows.Add(myrow);
```

but nothing displayed. Any idea why?
All I need is to display a table with 3 columns and n number of rows. This number will of rows will be dependent on number of records in database satisfying a certain conditions.

I also tried this:

```
HtmlTable table1 = new HtmlTable();

// Set the table's formatting-related properties.
table1.Border = 1;
table1.CellPadding = 3;
table1.CellSpacing = 3;
table1.BorderColor = "red";

// Start adding content to the table.
HtmlTableRow row;
HtmlTableCell cell;
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    // Create a new row and set its background color.
    row = new HtmlTableRow();
    row.BgColor = (i % 2 == 0 ? "lightyellow" : "lightcyan");

    for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
    {
        // Create a cell and set its text.
        cell = new HtmlTableCell();
        cell.InnerHtml = "Row: " + i.ToString() +
          "<br>Cell: " + j.ToString();

        // Add the cell to the current row.
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
    }

    // Add the row to the table.
    table1.Rows.Add(row);
}

// Add the table to the page.
this.Controls.Add(table1);
```

but it didn't work!

Comment: You haven't said anything about how you were trying to *use* `dTbl`, or what happened in your second example.

Comment: Which page's event handler this code placed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing "this.Controls.Add(table1)" add the table to the .aspx page, and then modify it through the code.

Even better - use a databound GridView.

Comment: Thanks for the hint...will try it out but I believe this is it :)